# Stop Tracking images

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

It is possible that Vuforia, once it has detected an image of your BBDD stop trying to find more images, keeping a 3D object in the last detected position fixed and that you can move the camera in extended tracking mode around the object 3D?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like this is a duplicate of this: stackoverflow.com/questions/17087725/how-to-make-vuforia-stop-tracking-in-unity

Comment: if use this code TrackerManager.Instance.GetTracker<ImageTracker>().Stop(); visual studio could not be found a definition for ImageTracker and the same with this TrackerManager.Instance.GetTracker(Tracker.Type.IMAGE_TRACKER).Stop(); visual not cotain a definition for type        thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to stop tracking when you want to, and keep a 3D object fixed at the last 2D position **on the screen** / viewport. But extended tracking is still tracking, so you cannot keep the 3D object fixed at the last position **in 3D space** once you disable tracking, as that is what tracking is for! :) If you'd like to then use other ways to *continue* tracking (you mention gyroscope), that is not an easy problem.

To disable the camera's tracking, but keep the camera feed, you would use something like:

```
Tracker imageTracker = TrackerManager.Instance.GetTracker<ObjectTracker>();
if (imageTracker != null)
    imageTracker.Stop();
```

It would not make sense to just put that code above in the `OnTrackingFound()` function in the `DefaultTrackableEventHandler` (if you are using that, otherwise your equivalent), as a trackable will usually be detected at the edges of the camera image, so if you disable the tracking immediately, the object would be stuck at the edge of your viewport somewhere. So you would probably use a timer, or best is to have the user push a UI button to 'freeze' the object.

You would also need to change the `OnTrackingLost()` function in the `DefaultTrackableEventHandler` to no longer disable the mesh renderer of your 3D object once tracking is 'lost' when tracking is stopped, otherwise the object would disappear.

Why not switch over to a 3D mode that is not AR, instead, where you can manipulate the object with your fingers on a mobile screen, or with a mouse or keyboard? In other words, disable Vuforia but keep the 'detected' 3D object active on screen. Instead of disabling the ObjectTrackers as in the code above, you would then disable Vuforia entirely, with:

```
VuforiaBehaviour.Instance.enabled = false;
```

You would still need to edit `OnTrackingLost()` (or equivalent) to no longer disable the 3D object once tracking is 'lost' when Vuforia is disabled.

Comment: I see that what I want to do is complicated.
I am creating an application that detects images and places characters near them,to do this use extended tracking, which in theory makes that the characters persist in space once the image is lost.
in practice often characters disappear for no apparent reason when the mobile phone camera moves, despite making the move slowly and that does not make sense to me.
What I commented at the beginning, was the first thing that occurred to me to solve it, But if you know other ways to solve it I would be happy to listen : )

Comment: Please accept my answer if I have answered your question.

I've just tested the quality of the extended tracking, it works very well for me, even with a 3-star target image. If I move the camera slowly, I am able to move/rotate the camera far away from the target without 'losing' it. There is then some unavoidable drift of the 3D model, but that is to be expected. If your tracking is not working very well, check that your target image is good quality for tracking / 5 stars in Vuforia's Target Manager.

Q: Why do you want to keep the character if the camera loses sight of the target image?

Comment: Another thing to consider, is how extended tracking works. The camera detects features in the frames of images that it sees, checks how those features have changed/moved, and estimates its own movement. So if your target image is e.g. on a plain desk that has no other distinguishing features, the camera cannot figure out its own relative movement. So to improve the extended tracking when the camera loses sight of the target image, the background / what else the camera sees has to be 'busy' / have other features which can be tracked, something like a plain desk will not work well.

Comment: i want that the player could interact with the character and have a dialogue with him. if the phone lost the character for a moment its a very big problem for me. Sorry for not check the answerd, i m new in the forum. it is a group of images with a detection rate of three to four stars and sometimes the characters blink for no reason

Comment: Can you explain why it's a big problem if tracking is momentarily lost? Is it not possible to, e.g.: 1. keep a variable which says whether the conversation has started, 2. keep another variable which says whether / where the conversation is paused. Then when you find the target, if the variable that the conversation has started has not been set to true, set it to true. If it is true but the conversation is paused, continue the conversation. When you lose tracking, pause the conversation. Then the conversation only happens when you are tracking the target, and simply pauses when you are not.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you are trying to accomplish is something along the lines of [Dead Reckoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_reckoning).

The reason we can't really get proper dead reckoning with a mobile device (assuming that is what you are running Vuforia on) is because the internal sensors are not nearly accurate enough to maintain a proper location between this frame and the last frame. Unity may think you are a few inches to the left, when in reality you are much further. This will create a very heavy drift effect and will likely kill the "magic" feel of the simulation all together. Something like a Google Tango is much better at this type of thing, though those rely on environment recognition, not target recognition. Tangos can recieve new environment data every frame, making it much more stable.

Since (most) mobile devices don't have depth sensors or anything like that, Vuforia relies on the image targets as a way to anchor your object in the scene, giving it a constantly updating location every frame. This way, it doesn't have to rely on anything like accelerometer data to compensate.

You **can** disable tracking, but it will do exactly that, disable tracking and leave your object floating off into the virtual abyss (if you manage to override the renderer manipulation from vuforia).

In a nutshell, Vuforia needs the image target in order to track properly, eliminating the probability of the 'last known position' technique.

Comment: I try to disable with this code TrackerManager.Instance.GetTracker<ImageTracker>().Stop(); but visual studio could not be found a definition for ImageTracker and the same with this TrackerManager.Instance.GetTracker(Tracker.Type.IMAGE_TRACKE‌​R).Stop(); visual not cotain a definition for type thanks. If i could disable tracking and  position the image at the same distance from the camera and gyroscope to look the other direcion keeping used the image in his position, it would be great. sorry for my english